# How to add another line on overflow in a text input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create more text area for the user ( A new empty line ), when the user has filled out the textbox completely.

I'm not sure whether I can do this with CSS or if I need to use JS.

I **don't** want the text to keep continuing in the same amount of area, like what happens by default.

My Question is: How can I make my tag: `<input type="text" />`, automatically display a new empty text line when the initial text area is filled out, instead of continuing the text in the same area?

Comment: you should use a `textarea`.

Comment: Yes however, <textarea> is a tag I find very annoying in terms of browser-dependant features (scroll bar, draggable size) Is there any other way?

Comment: you can modify those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `<textarea>` instead of an `<input type="text">`. It is multiline by design.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <textarea>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ornare elementum sapien sit amet vestibulum. Maecenas et convallis lacus.
    <textarea></textarea>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
   function textareaResize(e) {
      $(e).css({'height':'auto','overflow-y':'hidden'}).height(e.scrollHeight);
    }
    $('textarea').each(function () {
      textareaResize(this);
    }).on('input', function () {
      textareaResize(this);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `textarea` to get multiline handling.

```
<textarea name="Text1" cols="40" rows="5" ... ></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<textarea>` tag, you need!